# Create new field in SugarCRM

Tags: field, sugarcrm

I'm trying to add new field in SugarFields and i have many problems. I have to create a new field which is combination of relate field and multienum, when user clicks to select one/many item(s) the list will be loaded to dropdown list (multiselect). I have copied and modified relate field but i can't see how to get data from pop-up window
Have anyone tried this before? Please give me a clue. I'm using SugarCE-6.5.13
Thank you.

I can't upload image so this is a link from mediafire :(
http://www.mediafire.com/view/523c1kwewld18hn#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a custom field. What you actually want to do is add some custom JavaScript that will make an ajax call to the server to obtain the values for the multi-select from the relate.

There are two different types of data for a relate field. Data when you type ahead and data that is returned from a popup.

For the popup: you will need to override the **function set_return(popup_reply_data)** 
I can't remember off the top of my head, how to handle the type ahead.

Comment: Thank you NEPO, I will follow your hint :)